# Preprocessing an element before handing off to imported template

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm not an XSL guru, but a motivated amateur learning as I go. I'm working on an XSL stylesheet that imports a large library of templates I don't own and would like to leave alone.

I'm trying to figure out a way to intercept a particular element and make a small change before handing it off to an imported template. Specifically, I want to modify an attribute value on `<image>` elements, but otherwise allow processing to proceed as usual. It seems like this should be doable, but I'm stumped.

This is what I currently have, which doesn't work:

```
<!-- intercept image elements before imported template sees them -->
<xsl:template match="image" name="image_intercept">
  <!-- preprocess image element and capture it in a variable -->
  <xsl:variable name="preprocessed_image">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="preprocess-image" />
  </xsl:variable>
  <!-- Now send the modified version on to the imported template....
       except of course this doesn't work -->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$preprocessed_image" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="preprocess_image">
  <!-- For this example I'll just copy it through unchanged.
       In reality I'll change an attribute value. -->
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

This fails, as I expected it would, because the `image_intercept` template ends up looping. I don't want to match on the same template again; instead I want to hand off `$preprocessed_image` to the imported template that matches `<image>` elements. But I can't figure out a way to do that. I tried this:

```
...
<!-- apply templates with mode to avoid looping -->
<xsl:apply-templates select="$preprocessed_image" mode="passthrough"/>
...

<!-- hand off processing to imported template -->
<xsl:template match="*" mode="passthrough">
  <xsl:apply-imports/>
</xsl:template>
```

But that doesn't work because `<xsl:apply-imports>` inherits the template mode (`"passthrough"`), and the imported template I'm trying to hand off to has no mode).

I'd appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

If the attribute servers for distinguishing the element then perhaps using it in the match patterns, as in

```
<!-- intercept image elements before imported template sees them -->
<xsl:template match="image[not(@att-name)]" name="image_intercept">
  <!-- preprocess image element and capture it in a variable -->
  <xsl:variable name="preprocessed_image" as="element()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="preprocess-image" />
  </xsl:variable>
  <!-- Now send the modified version on to the imported template....
       except of course this doesn't work -->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$preprocessed_image" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="preprocess_image">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="att-name" select="'foo'"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="image[@att-name]">
  <xsl:apply-imports/>
</xsl:template>
```

allows you to avoid the mode problem.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not seeing how that will work. If I just invoke `xsl:next-match` in my `image-intercept` template, it will act on the context node (the unmodified `image`) rather than the modified version in the `$preprocessed_image` variable.

Comment: @rrberry, I have made a different suggestion, see the edited answer.